# Postgresql - pg_stat_statements shows only users' records

Tags: postgresql

When I query `pg_stat_statements` it shows only mine queries/records. Even if I query the view under superadmin I still see only the records of the same user.

```sql
-- PostgreSQL 14.6 with TimescaleDB extension
SHOW pg_stat_statements.track
> all
SELECT * FROM pg_policies WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = 'pg_stat_statements';
> No rows
```

How to see queries of *all* users?

Comment: You just need to have a superuser account - "postgres" or similar. You wouldn't like it if other user accoiunts could see `INSERT INTO secret_passwords VALUES (...)`

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I see a bunch of records for other users which provide '<insufficient privilege>' for the query string.

Comment: What is a 'superadmin'?  Is that the same thing as a superuser, or is it some term invented by a cloud provider to obscure what is really going on?